# Pronominalization: a handbook for secret agents

Tags: generative-grammar

I recently learnt that Edward Witten, the world's best string theorist [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Witten), wrote a paper on generative grammar, called

> "Pronominalization: a handbook for secret agents",

as you can see from [Google Search](https://www.google.co.jp/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=Pronominalization%3a%20a%20handbook%20for%20secret%20agents&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&redir_esc=&ei=kO6_UfnoLMKWkwWBw4GADw). Also see footnote 98 at [this book](http://books.google.co.jp/books?id=JNi58Gqm8qYC&lpg=PA69&ots=vZS3RvtBpz&dq=Pronominalization%3a%20a%20handbook%20for%20secret%20agents&pg=PA53#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Apparently it's an unpublished thesis from Brandeis University. Is there a way to get a copy of it?

Comment: This is not an appropriate question for this site. Nevertheless, I did some searching and found that it's not available thru the Brandeis library (including theses and dissertations requests). I suggest you try contacting Edward Witten at the IAS (probably best to contact his departmental staff). And if you have success, see if he's willing to put it online somewhere!

Comment: Can't this be edited and re-opened as a reference request question?

Comment: This interest has piqued my curiosity. So far it does indeed seem difficult to find much information about Witten's linguistics work. I'm with @DangerFourpence in thinking the question can probably be salvaged as it's clearly about linguistics and not trivial to answer.